# distance detection and prevention methods

Tags: proximity-sensor

Assume we have a security camera in front door attached to door itself and students trying block it by any possible object (solid/liquid/small/big). we want a proximity-sensor to Alert manager if any particle reach its distance limit area (for example we set 10cm distance limit and if anything try pass through this border, sensor must Alert). What is the cheapest sensor which for example use radiowave/infrared to detect any type of coming particles with any size and how much is false positive ratio ?

Comment: You might want to see: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30847/building-a-waterproof-and-cheap-proximity-detector

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a Passive Infrared sensor for the purpose:

[image: PIR sensor]
[image: PIR sensor detail]
<sub>*Images from eBay listings.*</sub>

You can find a [prebuilt module like the one above](http://www.ebay.com/itm/HC-SR501-Adjust-IR-Pyroelectric-Infrared-PIR-Motion-Sensor-Detector-Module-/200875812157?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2ec521a53d) on sites like eBay, for as little as US$1.50 including international shipping.

The module linked above has sensitivity adjustment, so it can be tuned to react to motion within a specific range. 10 cm may be too small a distance, beyond the lowest sensitivity setting, as per an experiment I just did. The minimum sensitivity setting seems to represent about 90 cm.

False positives are very low at the low sensitivity you would operate this module at.

Using such PIR modules is very simple: They need a DC supply of (typically) 3.3 to 5 Volts, very low current required, and the signal line goes high when motion is detected, falling back to low after an adjustable period (the second preset on the module).

Coding for it is simple too: There are several open source examples for using these modules with [Arduino](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PIRsense), [MSP430 Launchpad](http://blog.suspended-chord.info/2010/09/12/connecting-a-parallax-pir-sensor-module-to-the-launchpad), and various PIC, ATmega and ATtiny microcontrollers .